# Is it possible to use a std::pair as (sole) template argument for an associative container like std::map?

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

The title may not be descriptive enough for what I would like to know:
Consider this code:

```
typedef std::pair<std::string, int> myPair;
typedef std::map<std::string, int> myMap;
```

As you can see, both typedefs use the same template arguments.
Now, I want to ensure, that both typedefs always use the same template arguments.
A somewhat roundabout way to achieve this may be:

```
typedef arg1 std::string;
typedef arg2 int;

typedef std::pair< arg1, arg2 > myPair;
typedef std::map< arg1, arg2 > myMap;
```

Now, I'm wondering, if there is a nicer way, something akin to:

```
typedef std::pair<std::string, int> myPair;
typedef std::map< myPair > myMap;
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers into the right direction!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <map>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
struct make_map;

template <typename K, typename V>
struct make_map<std::pair<K,V> >
{
    typedef std::map<K,V> type;
};
```

Test:

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    typedef std::string arg1;
    typedef int arg2;

    typedef std::pair<arg1, arg2> myPair;
    typedef make_map<myPair>::type myMap;

    myMap m;
    m["foo"] = 1;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/372b1b8878159b1c)

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a nice solution!